# Android SQlite-MySQL database sync query

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, gson, android-sqlite

I am trying to implement a database sync code (from the tutorial at [programmer guru](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/)) where data in an android app is synchronised to a remote mysql server through the function `syncMsgUpload()`. I have implemented the code well but when I run the code, my app crashes. Kindly assist me in getting the code right. The android studio logcat is giving the following error:

```
08-22 23:15:32.243  13248-13248/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.skibzy.skibzydesigns.MessageActivity.syncMsgUpload(MessageActivity.java:214)
        at com.skibzy.skibzydesigns.MessageActivity$2$1.onMenuItemClick(MessageActivity.java:138)
        at android.widget.PopupMenu.onMenuItemSelected(PopupMenu.java:142)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:160)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1139)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2856)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3619)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My DBHelper and Activity files are as below:

**DBHelper**

```
public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(
            "create table " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + MESSAGES_USER_ID + " integer, "
                    + MESSAGES_COLUMN_SUBJECT + " text, "
                    + MESSAGES_COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text, "
                    + MESSAGES_STATUS + " text, "
                    + MESSAGES_SYNC_STATUS + " text, "
                    + MESSAGES_WEB_ID + " text, "
                    + MESSAGES_CREATED_AT + " text)"
    );
    db.execSQL(
            "create table " + CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID + " integer, "
                    + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_MESSAGE + " text, "
                    + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_TYPE + " text, "
                    + CONVERSATION_STATUS + " text, "
                    + CONVERSATION_SYNC_STATUS + " text, "
                    + CONVERSATION_WEB_ID + " text, "
                    + CONVERSATION_CREATED_AT + " text)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean createMessage  (String user_id, String subject, String category, String status, String msg, String unique) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_USER_ID, user_id);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_COLUMN_SUBJECT, subject);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_STATUS, status);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_SYNC_STATUS, "no");
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_WEB_ID, unique);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_CREATED_AT, time);
    long id = db.insert(MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    createConv(id, msg, "q", "1", unique);
    return true;
}

public boolean createConv  (long msg_id,String msg, String type, String status, String unique) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CONVERSATION_COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID, msg_id);
    contentValues.put(CONVERSATION_COLUMN_MESSAGE, msg);
    contentValues.put(CONVERSATION_COLUMN_TYPE, type);
    contentValues.put(CONVERSATION_STATUS, status);
    contentValues.put(CONVERSATION_SYNC_STATUS, "no");
    contentValues.put(CONVERSATION_WEB_ID, unique);
    contentValues.put(CONVERSATION_CREATED_AT, time);
    db.insert(CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

/*
public Cursor getData (int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID + " = " + id + "", null);
    return res;
}

public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}
*/

public Cursor getConvDetail(int id, String column) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery( "SELECT " + column + " FROM " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ID + " = " + id + "", null);
    return res;
}

public boolean updateMessage (Integer id, String user_id, String subject, String category, String status, String time, String msg)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_USER_ID, user_id);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_COLUMN_SUBJECT, subject);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_STATUS, status);
    contentValues.put(MESSAGES_CREATED_AT, time);
    db.update(MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, MESSAGES_COLUMN_ID +" = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name, String phone, String email, String street,String place)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("phone", phone);
    contentValues.put("email", email);
    contentValues.put("street", street);
    contentValues.put("place", place);
    db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts",
            "id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllMessages() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ID + " DESC", null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(MESSAGES_COLUMN_SUBJECT)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllConversations(Integer msgId) {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID  + " = " + msgId + " ORDER BY " + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_ID + " ASC", null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONVERSATION_COLUMN_MESSAGE)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}

/**
 * Get list of Messages from SQLite DB as Array List
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllMessagesSync() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> msgWordList;
    msgWordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ID + " DESC", null);
    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", res.getString(0));
            map.put("subject", res.getString(1));
            map.put("category", res.getString(2));
            map.put("status", res.getString(3));
            map.put("web_id", res.getString(5));
            map.put("created", res.getString(6));
            msgWordList.add(map);
        } while (res.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return msgWordList;
}

/**
 * Get list of Users from SQLite DB as Array List
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllConversationsSync(Integer msgId) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> convWordList;
    convWordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID  + " = " + msgId + " ORDER BY " + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_ID + " ASC", null);
    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", res.getString(0));
            map.put("msg_id", res.getString(1));
            map.put("message", res.getString(2));
            map.put("type", res.getString(3));
            map.put("status", res.getString(4));
            map.put("web_id", res.getString(6));
            map.put("created", res.getString(7));
            convWordList.add(map);
        } while (res.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return convWordList;
}

/**
 * Compose JSON out of SQLite records
 * @return
}
 */
public String msgComposeJSONphone(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String search = "no";
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MESSAGES_SYNC_STATUS + " = " + search + "", null);
    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", res.getString(0));
            map.put("subject", res.getString(1));
            map.put("category", res.getString(2));
            map.put("status", res.getString(3));
            map.put("web_id", res.getString(5));
            map.put("created", res.getString(6));
            wordList.add(map);
        } while (res.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    //Use GSON to serialize Array List to JSON
    return gson.toJson(wordList);
}

public String convComposeJSONphone(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CONVERSATION_SYNC_STATUS
            + " = no", null);
    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", res.getString(0));
            map.put("msg_id", res.getString(1));
            map.put("message", res.getString(2));
            map.put("type", res.getString(3));
            map.put("status", res.getString(4));
            map.put("web_id", res.getString(6));
            map.put("created", res.getString(7));
            wordList.add(map);
        } while (res.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    //Use GSON to serialize Array List to JSON
    return gson.toJson(wordList);
}

/**
 * Get Sync status of SQLite
 * @return
 */
public String getMsgSyncStatus(){
    String msg = null;
    if(this.dbMsgSyncCount() == 0){
        msg = "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!";
    }else{
        msg = "Message Sync needed\n";
    }
    return msg;
}

public String getConvSyncStatus(){
    String msg = null;
    if(this.dbConvSyncCount() == 0){
        msg = "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!";
    }else{
        msg = "Conversations Sync needed\n";
    }
    return msg;
}

/**
 * Get SQLite records that are yet to be Synced
 * @return
 */
public int dbMsgSyncCount(){
    int count = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MESSAGES_SYNC_STATUS
            + " = '"+"no"+"'", null);
    count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    return count;
}

public int dbConvSyncCount(){
    int count = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CONVERSATION_SYNC_STATUS
            + " = no", null);
    count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    return count;
}

/**
 * Update Sync status against each User ID
 * @param id
 * @param status
 */
public void updateMsgSyncStatus(String id, String status){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String updateQuery = "Update " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME + " set " + MESSAGES_SYNC_STATUS + " = '" + status +"' where " + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ID + " = '"+ id +"'";
    Log.d("query", updateQuery);
    database.execSQL(updateQuery);
    database.close();
}

public void updateConvSyncStatus(String id, String status){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String updateQuery = "Update " + CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME + " set " + CONVERSATION_SYNC_STATUS + " = '" + status +"' where " + CONVERSATION_COLUMN_ID + " = '"+ id +"'";
    Log.d("query", updateQuery);
    database.execSQL(updateQuery);
    database.close();
}
```

**Activity Code**

```
public class MessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ISideNavigationCallback {
//Utils Class
Utils util;

final Context context = this;

//TOOLBAR
private Toolbar toolbar;

//CONSTANT BUTTONS
private ImageButton btnCall;
private ImageButton btnMessage;
private ImageButton btnLocate;

//Side Menu
private ButtonAwesome menuBtn;
private SideNavigationView sideNavigationView;

private ListView obj;
DBHelper mydb;
//Progress Dialog Object
ProgressDialog prgDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
    util = new Utils(this);

    TextView appTit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appTitle);
    String pageTitle = "My Messages";
    appTit.setText((CharSequence)pageTitle);

    sideNavigationView = (SideNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.side_navigation_view);
    sideNavigationView.setMenuItems(R.menu.menu_main);
    sideNavigationView.setMenuClickCallback(this);
    sideNavigationView.setMode(SideNavigationView.Mode.LEFT);

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllMessages();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

    obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id_To_Search = arg0.getCount() - arg2;
            String sbj = "subject";
            String uniqueCode = "web_id";
            Cursor theSbj = mydb.getConvDetail(id_To_Search, sbj);
            Cursor theCode = mydb.getConvDetail(id_To_Search, uniqueCode);
            theSbj.moveToFirst();
            theCode.moveToFirst();
            String subject = theSbj.getString(theSbj.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MESSAGES_COLUMN_SUBJECT));
            String unique = theCode.getString(theCode.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MESSAGES_WEB_ID));

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
            dataBundle.putString("msgSubject", subject);
            dataBundle.putString("unique", unique);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewMessage.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    util.menuSwitch(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}

public void syncMsgUpload(){
    //Create AsycHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  mydb.getAllMessagesSync();
    if(userList.size()!=0){
        if(mydb.dbMsgSyncCount() != 0){
            prgDialog.show();
            params.put("msgJSON", mydb.msgComposeJSONphone());
            client.post("http://192.168.43.87/custserv/app/message/create_msg.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    try {
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                        System.out.println(arr.length());
                        for(int i=0; i<arr.length();i++){
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)arr.get(i);
                            System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                            System.out.println(obj.get("status"));
                            mydb.updateMsgSyncStatus(obj.get("id").toString(),obj.get("status").toString());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB Sync completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                                      String content) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if(statusCode == 404){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else if(statusCode == 500){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Messages", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void syncConvUpload(){
    //Create AsycHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  mydb.getAllMessagesSync();
    if(userList.size()!=0){
        if(mydb.dbConvSyncCount() != 0){
            prgDialog.show();
            params.put("convJSON", mydb.convComposeJSONphone());
            client.post("http://192.168.43.87/custserv/app/message/create_conv.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    try {
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                        System.out.println(arr.length());
                        for(int i=0; i<arr.length();i++){
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)arr.get(i);
                            System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                            System.out.println(obj.get("status"));
                            mydb.updateSyncStatus(obj.get("id").toString(),obj.get("status").toString());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB Sync completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                                      String content) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if(statusCode == 404){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else if(statusCode == 500){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data in SQLite DB, please do enter User name to perform Sync action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In your DBHelper in onCreate, you are closing your strings incorrectly.

Comment: Which strings and how do I correct them?

Comment: Nevermind, I have read something incorrectly. However, the error occurs in your activity in syncMsgUpload() method.

Comment: At some point logcat was giving the error `unknown column no` for the query `select * from message where sync = no`

Comment: In this large wall of code it's not easy for us to figure out what line is MessageActivity.java:214

Comment: The error was in the function `syncConvUpload()` and the line is the one beginning with `if(mydb.dbConvSyncCount() != 0){`

Comment: I sort it out. Seems I had not declared some variables utilized by `prgDialogue `